# Android Studio - make an activity scrollable without changing the current layout?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, scroll

I have an activity page that I have placed images, buttons, etc. on. I am realizing it's going to be too large to fit on a mobile screen, so I want to make the page scrollable.

My current xml file for the activity looks like the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".bakers"> 
...
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I searched online and have tried multiple solutions, but the problem with every solution is that, though sometimes I'm able to scroll on the page, the format/layout of the activity gets all messed up.

For example, if I do this:

```xml
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

       ...
```

the format is still messed up. I've also tried to use a Relative Layout setup, but that doesn't help either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share you full xml ? So that we can try it by our own . We can't say it unless we can look at the xml .

Answer (score 0):

add `scrollView` to the `.xml` file and put the objects that you want to be scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

try this guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=69C1ljfDvl0&t=287s
The code is in the description if you dont want to watch the video. hope it will help you.